# error installing mongodb on trusty

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, mongodb

I'm trying to install `mongodb` on the `trusty tahr` following this tutorial: `http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/`.

When running the first command (`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10`), I get this error:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.XG3SzDeMYM --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
gpg: requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Comment: Are you connected to internet ? If yes, proxies and all are configured properly ?

Comment: I do use a proxy. This might be the whole problem, yes. Is there any other method than requiring the key to install mongo?

Comment: You can export proxies temporarily by using these commands on terminal. export http_proxy="my.proxy:port"
export https_proxy="my.proxy:port" For more info : go through this thread. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1437659

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not able to resolve `keyserver.ubuntu.com`, see this line in your error:

> keyserver.ubuntu.com: Host not found

Testing it locally here suggests no issue with the hostname generally, but perhaps something up with your nameserver?

```
host keyserver.ubuntu.com
keyserver.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.89.49
keyserver.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.90.55
```

Worst case scenario you can manually add an address to your `/etc/hosts` file to workaround the problem and then figure it out later.  FYI, there can be issues with connecting to the keyserver with proxies and the like, see my answers on this (and others) [over on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/621258/113572).